# How to show command executing in the console and access its output in java

Tags: java, console, hidden

I have a command line tool that queries a server and prints the status of pending jobs to run.  This can take up to 30 seconds. I need to call this tool from java and I want to show its output in a text area on my GUI. For the purposes of example, lets say the command is "dir" in windows.

`Process.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");` blocks until the command finishes executing, so I thought it would be best to show the command executing in the terminal, then read the output and show it in my text area for future reference. However, the console is hidden giving the user the impression that the application has stopped working. After much research, I have tried:

`cmd /k dir` - runs in the background and can read output, but application hangs as it requires the /k switch means to keep the window open, but I can't see it to close it.

`cmd /c start dir` - opens in a new visible terminal, runs but doesn't close. Closing manually doesn't allow me to read the output

`cmd /k start dir` - same result as above

My question is, how can I spawn a command to run, see it running, and access its output?

Comment: `Runtime.exec` should not block until the command is finished, just until it is started and your process gets some processor time again.

Comment: It does in my scenario. It wont go to the next line in the code until the command specified in exec finishes running... is there a way I can access the output as it is written? I don't think so... it is an external process - it must finish executing before control is returned to the Java app to read the output. Being able to read the output as it is written would be great!!

Comment: exec() doesn't block. You can read and write to the external process. If it blocked, it would be almost useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Process proc = null;
String[] cmd = { "cmd", "/c", "dir" };
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

InputStream inputStream = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: This is the exact code I use to execute the command and read the output, but the console window does not pop up and show the command executing. How can I get the windows command prompt to display, execute the command showing the output, then allow me to read the output as above and display it in a text area?

Comment: Er ... you can't. The output would then be in the console window. You just create your own window and display what's going on. Make it look like a windows command window if you really want.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Is there a way that I can display the output in my command window as it is generated? It seems like you have to wait for the process to finish executing before you can iterate over the output. My command takes 30s to execute - I want to show the console output as it is written, not after the command has finished executing.

Comment: You are reading it as it is output by the external process. exec() doesn't block. If `dir` is taking that long to start outputting ... not much you can do about it. Fire up the exec() call in it's own thread so that your UI doesn't become unresponsive.

Comment: My apologies, exec doesn't block - its `bufferedReader.readLine()` that takes a while to execute, but only the first time. If there is no way to speed this process up (via another method or something) I need to look at optimising the way I am processing the output and updating my GUI.

Comment: Right ... the read is blocking, waiting for `dir` to start outputting. You can't make `dir` go any faster :) The reason subsequent runs are faster is because of filesystem caching

Comment: Thank you!! I have read in places that sometimes executing commands using exec in java takes longer due to additional setup and tear down overhead. Incorporating a SwingWorker to update the text area in the GUI enables it to update as the command is executing and not 'blocking' the rest of my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab its input / output / error stream using the process [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). but you need to  get the process object - `Process p = Process.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir");` see [this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534698/communicating-with-c-process-from-java).